# Can we see a list of all tasks across all project sites? For a particular user?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have multiple project sites, and we'd like to be able to see:

1. All tasks, across all projects.
2. All tasks, across all projects, for a particular user (but not the currently logged in user).

So far I haven't been able to figure out a way to accomplish this--is it possible in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0):

For getting all tasks you can use the below endpoint

```
<site url>/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/Tasks
```

For getting Tasks based on specific user you need to first use the below endpoint

```
<site url>/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectData/Assignments?$filter=ResourceName eq 'User Display Name'
```

In the results you will get the task endpoint and you can use that to get the task information